# Database always receiving same IDs

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I hope this is not a bad question. I've been trying to understand what I'm doing wrong but I can't.
I'm pretty new to php and mysql so I'm really confused...

I have this database (I will attach a mysql workbench model screenshot)
[image: mysql database]

And I'm trying to insert the sales into sale and print_for_sale tables. The queries seem to be working and the data shows up in phpmyadmin. No error pops up. However the sale user in the sale table is always the same id. Even if I use a different user login. And in the print_for_sale table the fk_sale_id is always the same id. And the price_print_for_sale is always the same as well. That is not supposed to happen. What am I doing wrong?
Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

[image: sale table]
[image: print_for_sale table]

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
print_r($_POST);

$id_print= $_POST['print_id'];

include('database.php');

$bought_sizes=$_POST['sizes'];

$number_of_bought_sizes= count($bought_sizes);


//header('location:index.php?area=printstore');


$sqlinsertsale = "insert into sale
    (fk_sale_user,
    fk_payment_id) 
    values(".$user_id.", 1)";
```

//payment is not yet defined so I'm using 1 just to try.

```
mysql_query($sqlinsertsale); 


for($i=0; $i< $number_of_bought_sizes; $i++){

    $selectmultiple = "select * 
    from print_has_size 
    inner join size on fk_size_id = size_id
    inner join print on fk_print_id = print_id 
    where print_id =".$id_print."";

    $resultmultiple = mysql_query($selectmultiple);

    $linemultiple = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultmultiple);

    $size_price = $linemultiple["size_price"];



    $selectsale = "select * 
    from sale";

    $resultsale = mysql_query($selectsale);

    $linesale = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsale);

    $sale_id = $linesale["sale_id"];

    //$sale_id = mysql_insert_id();

/*PARA CADA 1 DOS TAMNHO*/

$sqlinsertprintforsale = "insert into print_for_sale
    (fk_sale_id,
    price_print_for_sale) 
    values(".$sale_id.", ".$size_price.")";

mysql_query($sqlinsertprintforsale);

} 

?>
```

I'm also going to attach a screenshot of the selection page so you can see the markup in case it helps.

[image: markup]

Edit:
(I'm adding the php code from where I check the user login)

```
<?php
session_start();
include('database.php');

$user=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_login']);
$pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_pass']);

$sql="select user_id, user_name
    from user
    where
    user_login='".$user."' 
    and user_pass = MD5('".$pass."')";

    echo $sql;

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$num_of_regs = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<br>".$num_of_regs;

if($num_of_regs!=1) {
    header('location:index.php?login=done');
}
else {
    $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $user_name = $line['user_name'];
    $user_id = $line['user_id'];


    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

    header('location:index.php');


}

?>
```

And I did a log out system too.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location:index.php');
 ?>
```

Now I noticed that the sale table is not receiving data..
Only the print_for sale is. Wrong data still. Same IDs... Why?  :(

This is the only error message that I get when I used the code
     ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/printstore/database.php on line 7

Added

```
 echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

And this is my output for user 1:

[image: user1]

And for user 2:
[image: user2]

it seems to be ok, it recognizes user 1 and 2.
Table sale is not being refreshed when I make a "new purchase" and table print_for_sale is refreshed with the same sale id. Always 3 (as shown in the screenshot)

- I deleted every row from sale in phpmyadmin and tried again. It's working. Sale table seems to be working fine. The only problem now is the table print_for_sale which even when I use a different user (and it shows up ok in the sale table), it still shows the same sale_id and the same price_print_price which is always 25). And in this case I never selected anything costing 25.  -

[image: sale_now]
[image: print_for_sale_now]

Comment: Can you show us where you are setting `$_SESSION['user_id'];`

Comment: Already did @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ , Thank you!

Comment: Put this at the top of your PHP, and it'll help generate some error messages. Post up the errors you're getting.

`ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`


Also, on your Sales query, I see that you're setting the variable, but are you actually executing the query?

Comment: Thank you @Fata1Err0r ! This is my error message: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/printstore/database.php on line 7

Comment: can you add output of `$_SESSION['user_id']` for different 2 user session. login as a user than logout and do same thing again and please share with us

Comment: Did you use `mysql_query($sqlinsertsale);` for your sale query toward the top? ... Scratch that. I'm blind. ;)

Comment: Btw, just for the info... here is the newer extensions the error was talking about, though it isn't your problem at the moment.

`$dbConnection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);`

and for queries

`mysqli_query($dbConnection,$myquery);`

It's also worth learning to use `mysqli_free_result` and `mysqli_close()`

Comment: Thank you @Fata1Err0r! @hakkikonu, already added the output. thank you.

Comment: There is a possibility in you database design where you mentioned the default value as 1 and 3. If i am wrong, kindly excuse me. @hakkikonu is right. The $_SESSION['user_id'] for different 2 user session will lead towards the answer

Comment: Thank you. I think I got that wrong then. Did not quite understand how to set a $_SESSION['user_id'] for different 2 user sessions. @AlaksandarJesusGene

Comment: Btw, I notice that you use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` but you never put it into a loop to get each row's data before setting the field value to your variables. I'm not able to see your screenshots, so I don't know how your DB is set up, but that's worth trying if you're getting the same result, rather than each of the newer results.

Comment: last thing: replace `$user_id` to 999 for example in your insert queries. If there is no change, you have sql trouble. We will approach from that side.

Comment: Do I have to set up a new loop within a loop for the mysql_fetch_assoc()? Both $selectmultiple and $selectsale are within this loop: for($i=0; $i< $number_of_bought_sizes; $i++){ *here* } . Is this not what you mean @Fata1Err0r ?

Comment: @Owly I posted up an answer below for you so it's easier to see. Give that a shot, and more often than not, you'll want to use a loop when you do mysql_fetch_assoc(), even if it's nested in a different type of loop. Your first loop isn't dealing with those particular entries, or looping through your results from the DB.

Comment: I deleted every row from sale in phpmyadmin and tried again. It's working. Sale table seems to be working fine. The only problem now is the table print_for_sale which even when I use a different user (and it shows up ok in the sale table), it still shows the same sale_id and the same price_print_price which is always 25). And in this case I never selected anything costing 25. @hakkikonu

Comment: I am not sure but i remember using _ might be a problem too. I faced it once and dont remember exactly it was with PHP. and you $_SESSION['user_id']; why is it in array. Is it not a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot. It seems that you're getting the same result because you never loop through your results. Also make sure that your field names are exactly the same as your field names in your DB.

```
$selectsale = "select * 
from sale";

$resultsale = mysql_query($selectsale);

while($linesale = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsale))
{
 $sale_id = $linesale["sale_id"];
}
```

Comment: That definitely solved all my problems! Thank you so much! :)

I used the while for the price (the $selectmultiple) as well and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Very good! :) Because `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is an array, you'll want to make sure you always throw it into a loop to get each row (and perform any other functions you want on each row) or else it'll only return the one row to you. Although it doesn't seem to matter too much YET, I'd recommend reading up on mysqli vs mysql, since mysqli is meant to replace mysql.

Answer (score 1):

when you logout you should destroy your sessions

I assume you have a logout page like logout.php. In it you should set below lines. If you don't do that session values can't change.

```
<?php 

session_start();
session_destroy();

?>
```

Also if you store your user id on a session variable, only closing all browser windows than reopen and login will help you.

Extra info for you future code life: **WHY PDO** http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: Thank you @hakkikonu . I tried that and it still does the same. But now I noticed that the sale table is not receiving data anymore. Only the print_for_sale is